# wrapper command to record network use of a command

Tags: networking, linux-networking, tcp, shell

Is there any command like `time` that can record a process's network I/O stats and print them on exit?

Linux (and other *nix) has the `time` command that lets you record execution times - not just wall-clock time, but kernel and system CPU time, memory allocations, disk I/O activity and more. It's useful because it can be run as a simple command wrapper and tracks children too.

e.g.

```
$ TIME="t=%E; I/O=%I:%O" time find $HOME > /dev/null
t=0:08.78; I/O=821408:0
```

but the network counters `%r` and `%s` only count send()/recv() calls; no TCP and no data volume. So they're not useful for network activity.

I've confirmed with

```
TIME="t=%E; I/O=%I:%O" time wget $somewebsite -O /dev/null
```

that socket read/write doesn't count for I/O and nor do dummy devices. Same for stdio. It only seems to track filesystem reads and writes.

But where can I get network stats?

I know I could use numerous tools like:

- `wireshark` / `tshark` / `tcpdump`
- `ss` / `netstat`
- `lsof`
- `nethogs` / `iptraf` / `iftop` / `tcptrack`
- `strace` (slow, fine-grained)

but none of them make it simple to target just one process or process tree and record its total network activity over its lifetime.

I know it's possible to set `socat` up as a proxy. But that's also very awkward; it can't just run as a wrapper.

`perf` can do it, but it's very platform specific and can be fragile.

Surely there's something basic and commonplace out there that either:

- intercepts network calls with `LD_PRELOAD` and collects stats on them; or
- uses network namespaces (Linux) to collect all activity for the process group and measures that

?

Comment: It's a good question.  There is no ready answer for network traffic, but [bpftrace](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2018-10-08/dtrace-for-linux-2018.html) (Brendan Gregg) may offer the technology to create this.